# How to make the browser interpret the text as html content instead of plain text?

Tags: java, html, browser

I have a Java String mailContent as

```
<p><span style="background-color: #ff6600; font-family: arial black,avant garde; font-size: large;">Testing Correct Formatting</span></p>
```

which i encode with methods formatString and formatParagraph in jsp before sending to browser. Jsp code is below

```
<td valign="center" >
<%=StringFormat.formatParagraph(StringFormat.formatString(mailContent,StringFormat.ALL))%>
 </td>
```

Now with with above code snippet i see it simply printed as plain text(as the value of mailContent) not  as text with html tags. Due to which, i don't see
 the formmatted HTML content like  font size, background color, font family etc. Thing is if simply use below code, it shows formatted html content because
 i am not encoding the text now.

```
 <td valign="center" >
 <%=mailContent%>
 </td>
```

now how i can make the browser interpret the encoded content as  html tags as i dont want to remove the encoding?

For information , on browser side , when i do view  source i see below as it has been encoded

```
 &lt;p&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;background-color: #ff6600; font-family: arial black,avant garde; font-size: large;&quot;&gt;Testing Correct Formatting&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;<br/><br/>
```

Comment: See if the `StringFormat` method has an overloaded version where you can specify `false` for the escaping.

Comment: I couldn't get your questions, you don't want to remove encoding but still want browser to interpret tags as html? That's not possible Sir and it doesn't make sense either!

Comment: I meant "escaping". Not encoding. Why are you encoding it by the way?

Comment: for security concerns.Its a legacy system which i dont want to modify :(

Comment: What template language are you using?  What is "<%=.."?

Answer (score 1):

The browser makes its decision about the content type using HTTP header named `Content-Type`. You should send content type value `text/html`. It seems that you are sending now `text/plain`, so browser treats the content as a plain text.

Please take a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) for more details.

Comment: That was not the question. The OP says they inject `"<p>"` into a HTML file and it comes out as `&lt;p&gt;`. How to prevent that?

Comment: i have already mentioned <%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %> at the top of page

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" language="java"  %>



<%
request.setAttribute("Att","<p><span style=\"background-color: #ff6600; font-family: arial black,avant garde; font-size: large;\">Testing Correct Formatting</span></p>");
%>
<%= request.getAttribute("Att")%>

In place of value in setAttrbiute you can pass your string object.
```

Comment: Can you explain this answer please?  You should not just post code.  You are always answering _both_ the OP and posterity.